# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined - php

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, xampp

I'm having a problem where I made a website and I can successfully add data to every Student which works fine, however I'm trying to make a page, where I can basically search for the City(város in my php document) they live in, and it lists me all of those students data. I can succesfully insert into "város", however when I try to read the data, it doesn't work.

The Error message I get is:

> SELECT * FROM Diák WHERE város = :város
>
> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

my code is:

```
<?php

require "../config.php";
require "../common.php";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if (!hash_equals($_SESSION['csrf'], $_POST['csrf'])) die();

  try  {
    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

    $sql = "SELECT * 
            FROM Diák
            WHERE város = :város";

    $város = $_POST['város'];
    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindParam(':város', $város, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->execute();

    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
  } catch(PDOException $error) {
      echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
  }
}
?>
<?php require "../../../htdocs/test/public/templates/header.php";?>
        
<?php  
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if ($result && $statement->rowCount() > 0) { ?>
    <h2>Találatok</h2>

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Oktatási_id</th>
          <th>Vezeték név</th>
          <th>Keresztnév</th>
          <th>Évfolyam</th>
          <th>Születési dátum</th>
          <th>Város</th>
          <th>Utca</th>
          <th>Házszám</th>
          <th>Irányítószám</th>
          <th>Szak</th>
          <th>Kar</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <?php foreach ($result as $row) : ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo escape($row["oktatási_id"]); ?></td>
          <td><?php echo escape($row["vezeték_név"]); ?></td>
          <td><?php echo escape($row["kereszt_név"]); ?></td>
          <td><?php echo escape($row["évfolyam"]); ?></td>
          <td><?php echo escape($row["születési_dátum"]); ?></td>
          <td><?php echo escape($row["város"]); ?></td>
          <td><?php echo escape($row["utca"]); ?> </td>
          <td><?php echo escape($row["házszám"]); ?> </td>
          <td><?php echo escape($row["irányítószám"]); ?> </td>
          <td><?php echo escape($row["szak"]); ?> </td>
          <td><?php echo escape($row["kar"]); ?> </td>
        </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php } else { ?>
      <blockquote>Nem találtunk diákot, aki ilyen Városban lakna. <?php echo escape($_POST['város']); ?>.</blockquote>
    <?php } 
} ?> 

<h2>Városon alapuló keresés.</h2>

<form method="post">
  <input name="csrf" type="hidden" value="<?php echo escape($_SESSION['csrf']); ?>">
  <label for="város">Város</label>
  <input type="text" id="város" name="város">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="View Results">
</form>

<a href="public/index.php">Vissza a fő oldalra.</a>

<?php require "../../../htdocs/test/public/templates/footer.php"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently PDO doesn't understand named parameters that contain accented characters (I guess anything outside 7-bit ASCII). So change `:város` to `:varos`.